# CVN input field not accepting input on checkout all of the sudden

Tags: magento-community

All of the sudden the CVN input box will not accept input from a user on checkout:
https://www.everydayblade.com/checkout/onepage/

I do not know what changed and do not see a useful error. I've tried several browsers and I simply can not enter data into the field. How can I start to troubleshoot? Thank you as always.

I'm using Stripe payment gateway in test mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have a problem. Your CVN field is fine, and can receive input, but you gave a padding too big with this rule :

```
#local.css : 678
input.input-text, select, textarea {
    ...
    padding: 9px 20px;
    ...
}
```

You can check the value of the field by pasting this command in the console of your browser, it will make you see that the value is well here. (Or by removing the rule manually from the browser too)

```
jQuery("#stripe_cc_cid").val()
```

To correct this, you can set a new rule only for the element **#stripe_cc_cid**, and either removing the padding or making the width bigger.

Comment: I just learned two things there...thank you! This did the trick.